# Access files on client with qml using WebGL

Tags: c++, qt, qml, webgl

I have written a qml based application on a linux machine which is started with
"-platform webgl" for using on a remote client in the browser with webgl. With the qml FileDialog class I can only access the files from the linux machine, not from the remote client.
How can I archive this?

Maybe I have to write a separate part in the application to handle these remote network access or do I have to use javascript or html5?

Comment: You have to clarify your question. Now your question seems completely incomprehensible.

Comment: @folibis I have changed my question. Hopefully helps to understand it...

Answer (score 0):

Access is controlled by the browser. It's like trying to access local files from the JavaScript code of the webpage.